# How can add filters in custom grid magento 2 without UI component

Tags: filter, admin-panel, magento2.3.4, custom-grid

I have created a custom grid for reports in the admin without UI component. Now I want to add filters in the grid. Filters type Date-Range, Price-Range, Status.

```
<?php 
        protected function _prepareColumns() {
        $this->addColumn(
                'increment_id',
                [
                    'header' => __('Increment ID#'),
                    'index' => 'increment_id',
                ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
                'order_id',
                [
                    'header' => __('Order #'),
                    'index' => 'order_id',
                ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'created_at',
                [
                    'header' => __('Purchased On'),
                    'index' => 'created_at',
                ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'amount_payable',
                [
                    'header' => __('Actual Amount Paid'),
                    'index' => 'amount_payable',
                ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'amount_pay_later',
                [
                    'header' => __('Balance Payment'),
                    'index' => 'amount_pay_later',
                ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
                'grand_total',
                [
                    'header' => __('Grand Total'),
                    'index' => 'grand_total',
                ]
        );
        

        $this->addColumn(
                'status',
                [
                    'header' => __('Status'),
                    'index' => 'status',
                ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
                'method',
                [
                    'header' => __('Payment Method'),
                    'index' => 'method',
                ]
        );

                    
        $this->addColumn(
                'billing_name',
                [
                    'header' => __('Bill to Name'),
                    'index' => 'billing_name',
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
                'shipping_name',
                [
                    'header' => __('Ship to Name'),
                    'index' => 'shipping_name',
                ]
        );
 


        $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('custom/*/exportCsv', ['_current' => true]), __('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('custom/*/exportExcel', ['_current' => true]), __('Excel XML'));


        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->addColumn(
  'created_at',
    [
      'header' => __('Purchased On'),
      'index' => 'created_at',
      'type' => 'datetime'
    ]
);`
```

for status Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn(
            'website_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Website'),
                'index' => 'website_id',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => \companyName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Grid::getStatus()
            ]
        );
....
....
static public function getStatus()
        {
            $data_array=array(); 
            $data_array[0]='Inactive';
            $data_array[1]='Active';
            return($data_array);
        }
```